# What is the default background color of UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to figure out what the default colour is for the UITabBarController background... I think the RGB is 245,245,245 alpha=1 but can someone please correct me? Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: It depends on the color of the view behind the tabBar if it is translucent. However, if you want to just get the color of it, use the Digital Color Meter of your OSX.

Answer (score 2):

My color meter says 247, 247, 247.